# Backslash use in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

What is the difference between `print("this is \\ double backslash")` and `print("this is \\\\ double backslash")` as they are giving same answer ?

Comment: For me they give different answers I get \ and \\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of:

```
print("this is \\\ double backslash") # case 1
print("this is \\\\ double backslash") # case 2
```

which indeed outputs:

```
this is \\ double backslash
this is \\ double backslash
```

The reason is because in *case 1*, the first `\` is acting upon the `\` after it and the third is escaped automatically due to the whitespace that follows, whereas in *case 2*, the first and third `\` are acting upon the second and fourth respectively.  Thus, both cases result in two `\` to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Like many languages, Python allows you to use backslashes in string literals to enter special characters (like a newline) or escape otherwise untypeable characters (like quotes of the same type the string is quoted with).

Unlike in some other languages, when the following character is not one of the special characters that Python's string literals recognize (e.g. `t`, `n`, `\`, `"`), it will just assume that you meant to just type a literal backslash.

Four backslashes are just two escaped backslashes. When you enter three backslashes *followed by a space* Python escapes your third backslash automatically, meaning it also results in printing two backslashes.

You can see the difference if your third/fourth backslash is followed by e.g. a `t`:

```
>>> print("\\\\t")
\\t
>>> print("\\\t")
\
```